# Replace `'<'` as starting and `'>'` as ending phrases in a string with wanted value

Tags: python, string, replace, tuples

So say i have a simple python string:

```
s='Hello I am <name>, and i love to eat <food>'
```

So i want to remove those `'<name>'` and `'<food>'` style phrases with the wanted value.

So also i have a `tuple`:

```
r=('Jon Doe', 'Pizza')
```

So i want to replace those phrases with `r` values in order.

So desired result is:

```
'Hello I am Jon Doe and i love to eat Pizza'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way

```
>>> import re
>>> r = {'name': 'Jon Doe', 'food': 'Pizza'}
>>> s = 'Hello I am <name>, and i love to eat <food>'
>>> re.sub('<(\w+)>', lambda match: t[match.groups()[0]], s)
'Hello I am Jon Doe, and i love to eat Pizza'
```

Comment: Nice one!!! accepted and up-voted, regex can do this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` to transform it into a formatable string and `str.format` to fill it:

```
>>> s = s.replace("<", "{").replace(">", "}")
>>> r=('Jon Doe', 'Pizza')
>>> s.format(name=r[0], food=r[1])
'Hello I am Jon Doe, and i love to eat Pizza'
```

Using a loop and replacing the whole tags:

```
>>> for key, value in zip(("name", "food"), r):
...    s = s.replace("<{}>".format(key), value)
... 
>>> s
'Hello I am Jon Doe, and i love to eat Pizza'
```

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel, 8 minutes difference on posting... you took your time ;)

Comment: You don’t see new answers until a page refreshes;)

Comment: Now I added a comment and a variation ;)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel, no need for the variation. But good job anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

Using replace:

```
s='Hello I am <name>, and i love to eat <food>'

r = ('John Doe','Pizza')
print(s.replace('<','{').replace('>','}').format(name=r[0],food=r[1]))
```

Updated: My answer above was 8 minutes late another same answer. So here is a variation:

```
s='Hello I am <name>, and i love to eat <food>'

r = ('John Doe','Pizza')
d = {'name':r[0],'food':r[1]}

print(s.replace('<','{').replace('>','}').format(**d))
```

Comment: Wow... This is very smart, why couldn't i think of that, also you can use f-strings too. right?

Answer (score 1):

Is this sample string fixed?

s='Hello I am , and i love to eat '

If you can write it using { and } instead of < and >, then a simple format can do this job.

```
s = 'Hello I am {name}, and i love to eat {food}'
name, food = ('Jon Doe', 'Pizza')
print  print s.format(name=name, food=food)
```

Answer (score 0):

## First way, `str.join` + `str.split`:

So just simply split the string by spaces, then iterate trough it, and if the iterator value is starting with `'<'` and ending with `'>'`, just simple make it as `%s`, then you `%` with the tuple `r`.

**1. `%s`**:

```
>>> s=' '.join([i if i[0]!='<' and i[-1]!='>' else '%s' for i in s.split()])
>>> s%r
'Hello I am Jon Doe and i love to eat Pizza'
>>>
```

**2. `str.format`**:

```
>>> s=' '.join([i if i[0]!='<' and i[-1]!='>' else '{}' for i in s.split()])
>>> s.format(*r)
'Hello I am Jon Doe and i love to eat Pizza'
>>>
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of this post if you already have an answer?

Comment: @SilverSlash It is acceptable on SO for a user to post an answer to his own question, particularly if the question is quite common, and the poster is attempting to create an answer or series of answers to hopefully address the question for future posters. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).